# Can't get attributes from AD using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, attributes, ldap

I use below code to get first name, last name, email, and department from AD using VB.Net 1.1

```
Public Shared Function GetAttribute(ByVal username As String, ByVal pwd As String) As UserInfo
        Dim objUserInfo As New UserInfo
        Dim ObjFirstName As String = ""
        Dim ObjLastName As String = String.Empty
        Dim ObjEmail As String = ""
        Dim objDepartment As String = ""
        Dim Success As Boolean = False

        Dim LDAPAddress As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("LDAPAddress")
        Dim Entry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(LDAPAddress, username, pwd)
        Dim Searcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry)
        Searcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.OneLevel
        Dim Filter As String = "(samAccountName=" & username & ")"
        Dim findUser As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(Entry, Filter)
        Dim results As SearchResultCollection = findUser.FindAll


        Try
            Dim Resultsx As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne
            Success = Not (Resultsx Is Nothing)

            findUser.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
            Dim name As String = DirectCast(Resultsx.Properties(name)(0), String)

            Dim de As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = Resultsx.GetDirectoryEntry()
            Dim gg = de.Properties.PropertyNames()

            For Each Onn As String In gg
                Dim str As String = String.Format("{0}", Onn)
            Next

            Try
                ObjFirstName = de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString()


                ObjEmail = de.Properties("mail").Value.ToString()

                ObjLastName = de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()
                objDepartment = de.Properties("department").Value.ToString()

            Catch ex As Exception
                ObjFirstName = de.Properties("DisplayName").Value.ToString()
            End Try
```

But I can't get those attributes. in

Dim str As String = String.Format("{0}", Onn)

there are only 15 attributes, and there are no firstname, lastname, email, and department. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, though old-fashioned, looks fine on first sight. If you insist to continue with your code, I'll have a look later.

In the meantime, this code should fit your situation:

```
    Dim user As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("UserDN")
    Dim src As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(user, "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person))")

    src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
    src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName")
    src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
    src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department")

    Dim res As SearchResult = src.FindOne

    Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("sn")(0))
    Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("givenName")(0))
    Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("mail")(0))
    Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("department")(0))

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code but didn't work. It said "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: @C.PurS That's the error message if one of the attributes of your defined User is empty

Comment: Yeah I did something wrong. It works well now when I used vb 2005. but still doesn't work in .net 1.1

Comment: It actually should work for .NET 1.1 as well.. (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I work in workgroup area, may it be the problem? But I can authenticate AD login perfectly, just can't get those properties

Comment: @C.PurS Probably.. I'm not aware of the behavior of DirectoryServices if the client isn't part of the domain..